# Limit amount of records displayed in javascript or jquery .each loop to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to limit the amount of data in my javascript .each loop to only 5 records

This works but certainly seems like OLD SCHOOL Hack...

```
var count = 0;

        $.each(allData, function (index, news) {

            if (count >= 5) {
                return false;

            } else {
                var dateString = news.created;
                var date = new Date(dateString);
                var formattedDateString = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + date.getDate() + "/" + date.getFullYear().toString().substr(2, 2);

                strResult += "<li><ul>" + formattedDateString + " : <a target='_parent' href='http://" + dochomenotlocal + "/doc-home/#/tips/2?paginatePage=1'>" + news.title + "</a> By: " + news.createdby + "</ul></li>";

                count++;
            }

        });
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: question was on limiting records , but without doing it sloppy old school hack way ,  both the answers provided are better,  and the slice answer is really most ideal to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Object.keys()` to create an array of property names of `allData`, `Array.prototype.slice()` to slice first 5 items within array returned by `Object.keys()` , `$.map()` to iterate on 5 property names within `allData`

```js
var data = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
  e: 5,
  f: 6,
  g: 7
};
// 
$.map(Object.keys(data).slice(0, 5), function(name, index) {
  // do stuff with first 5 property names within `data`
  
  $("body").append(data[name]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning `false` is the correct way to break out of a jQuery `each` so I think that's fine. However to make it more readable and explicit that you're limiting the loop to 5 iterations, you should probably just use a regular old `for` loop.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5 && i < allData.length; i++){
    // iterate
}
```